How can I specify a remote IP as default gateway in client OS
My client OS is Windows, and local IP is 172.16.2.21. The default gateway is 172.16.2.1, which is a 3-Layer switch. And the NAT router is 172.16.100.254. The client can access Internet.
Now I wanted to test a new router and a new Internet line. The new router IP is 172.16.101.254. But I didn't want to change 3-Layer switch configuration before I verified the new devices and configs.
So I tried to change routing table in Client OS only. I removed the default routing 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, and added two static routing 172.16.0.0/16 via 172.16.2.1, and 0.0.0.0/0 via 172.16.101.254. So the routing table looks like this.
Network     Mask         Gateway         Interface    Metrics
0.0.0.0     0.0.0.0      172.16.101.254  172.16.2.21  6
172.16.0.0  255.255.0.0  172.16.2.1      172.16.2.21  6

I can ping to 172.16.101.254, but cannot ping Internet IPs like 8.8.8.8. The ping command returned network unreachable or timeout. What's wrong?

A gateway is a host on the same network that knows how to reach other networks. You are trying to dictate routing from the host, and that is not how it works.

But I could do similar thing in the 3-Layer switch. Is this a limitation in host OS only?

A layer-3 switch is a gateway (router). It will have connections in multiple networks, and the next hop of any network is another device in that network. Putting on a gateway (next hop) of a different network would require a gateway to reach the gateway.
